# thrust:fill compile errors

Tags: cuda, fill, thrust

I'm need some help tracking down the compile errors that **thrust::fill** is giving me.

There is nothing wrong with the code:

```
line 9   #include <thrust/device_vector.h>                // needed for other thrust stuff
line 10  #include <thrust/fill.h>                        // not needed (same err w/ or w/o)
.
.
line 389 thrust::device_vector<int> junk(20);           // any ol array
line 390 thrust::fill(junk.begin(), junk.end(), (int)0); // the problem line
```

It will compile fine if I comment out the 'fill' line.
Any (raw_pointer, device_vector,..) thrust::**fill** command that I use will generate this error.  Other THRUST cmds compile fine.
The error is a few pages long.  I am not sure what the error is.  'for_each' is mentioned a lot.  The last one with 'compute_capability' makes no sense, as it is not in any of my code.  I tried adding a bunch of '#include ' files, but it didn't help any.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/for_each.h:54:0,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:23,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.h:55,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/for_each.inl:22,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/for_each.h:91,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/swap_ranges.inl:25,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/swap.inl:33,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/swap.h:127,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/contiguous_storage.inl:20,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/contiguous_storage.h:92,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/uninitialized_array.h:26,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/copy_cross_space.inl:20,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/copy_cross_space.h:57,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/dispatch/copy.h:23,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/copy.h:21,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/dispatch/copy.h:24,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/copy.inl:20,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/copy.h:44,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/copy.inl:20,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/copy.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/reference_base.inl:18,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/reference_base.h:138,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/device_reference.h:27,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device_ptr.inl:23,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/device_ptr.h:181,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/device_malloc_allocator.h:25,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/device_vector.h:25,
                 from /home/rrob/workspace/dicol/klm/src/Map.cpp:9:
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/for_each.inl: In function ‘RandomAccessIterator thrust::detail::backend::cuda::for_each_n(RandomAccessIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with RandomAccessIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]’:
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:56:63:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::dispatch::for_each_n(OutputIterator, Size, UnaryFunction, thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:126:62:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::for_each_n(OutputIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/for_each.inl:39:57:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::for_each_n(OutputIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/generate.inl:51:100:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::generate_n(OutputIterator, Size, Generator) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long int, Generator = thrust::detail::fill_functor<int>]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/fill.inl:93:43:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::cuda::detail::fill_n(OutputIterator, Size, const T&, thrust::detail::false_type) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long int, T = int, thrust::detail::false_type = thrust::detail::integral_constant<bool, false>]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/fill.inl:123:64:   [ skipping 3 instantiation contexts ]
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/fill.inl:93:60:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::fill_n(OutputIterator, Size, const T&) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long int, T = int]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/generic/fill.h:51:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::detail::backend::generic::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/fill.inl:51:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::detail::backend::dispatch::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&, Backend) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int, Backend = thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/fill.inl:83:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::detail::backend::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/fill.inl:34:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int]’
/home/rrob/workspace/dicol/klm/src/Map.cpp:390:49:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/for_each.inl:96:1: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘thrust::detail::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’ 
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/for_each.inl: In function ‘RandomAccessIterator thrust::detail::backend::cuda::for_each_n(RandomAccessIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with RandomAccessIterator = thrust::device_ptr<int>, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]’:
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:56:63:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::dispatch::for_each_n(OutputIterator, Size, UnaryFunction, thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag) [with OutputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<int>, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:126:62:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::for_each_n(OutputIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with OutputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<int>, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/generic/for_each.inl:36:84:   instantiated from ‘InputIterator thrust::detail::backend::generic::for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction) [with InputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<int>, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:91:67:   instantiated from ‘InputIterator thrust::detail::backend::dispatch::for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction, Space) [with InputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<int>, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >, Space = thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:136:61:   instantiated from ‘InputIterator thrust::detail::backend::for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction) [with InputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<int>, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/for_each.inl:48:58:   [ skipping 7 instantiation contexts ]
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/fill.inl:93:60:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::fill_n(OutputIterator, Size, const T&) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long int, T = int]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/generic/fill.h:51:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::detail::backend::generic::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/fill.inl:51:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::detail::backend::dispatch::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&, Backend) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int, Backend = thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/fill.inl:83:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::detail::backend::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/fill.inl:34:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int]’
/home/rrob/workspace/dicol/klm/src/Map.cpp:390:49:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/for_each.inl:96:1: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘thrust::detail::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’ 
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/for_each.inl: In function ‘RandomAccessIterator thrust::detail::backend::cuda::for_each_n(RandomAccessIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with RandomAccessIterator = thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int>, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<unsigned int> >]’:
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:56:63:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::dispatch::for_each_n(OutputIterator, Size, UnaryFunction, thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag) [with OutputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int>, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<unsigned int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:126:62:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::for_each_n(OutputIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with OutputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int>, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<unsigned int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/generic/for_each.inl:36:84:   instantiated from ‘InputIterator thrust::detail::backend::generic::for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction) [with InputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int>, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<unsigned int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:91:67:   instantiated from ‘InputIterator thrust::detail::backend::dispatch::for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction, Space) [with InputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int>, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<unsigned int> >, Space = thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:136:61:   instantiated from ‘InputIterator thrust::detail::backend::for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction) [with InputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<unsigned int>, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<unsigned int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/for_each.inl:48:58:   [ skipping 7 instantiation contexts ]
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/fill.inl:93:60:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::fill_n(OutputIterator, Size, const T&) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long int, T = int]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/generic/fill.h:51:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::detail::backend::generic::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/fill.inl:51:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::detail::backend::dispatch::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&, Backend) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int, Backend = thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/fill.inl:83:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::detail::backend::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/fill.inl:34:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int]’
/home/rrob/workspace/dicol/klm/src/Map.cpp:390:49:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/for_each.inl:96:1: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘thrust::detail::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’ 
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/for_each.inl: In function ‘RandomAccessIterator thrust::detail::backend::cuda::for_each_n(RandomAccessIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with RandomAccessIterator = thrust::device_ptr<long long unsigned int>, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<long long unsigned int> >]’:
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:56:63:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::dispatch::for_each_n(OutputIterator, Size, UnaryFunction, thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag) [with OutputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<long long unsigned int>, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<long long unsigned int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:126:62:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::for_each_n(OutputIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with OutputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<long long unsigned int>, Size = long int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<long long unsigned int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/generic/for_each.inl:36:84:   instantiated from ‘InputIterator thrust::detail::backend::generic::for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction) [with InputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<long long unsigned int>, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<long long unsigned int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:91:67:   instantiated from ‘InputIterator thrust::detail::backend::dispatch::for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction, Space) [with InputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<long long unsigned int>, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<long long unsigned int> >, Space = thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/for_each.inl:136:61:   instantiated from ‘InputIterator thrust::detail::backend::for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction) [with InputIterator = thrust::device_ptr<long long unsigned int>, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::device_generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<long long unsigned int> >]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/for_each.inl:48:58:   [ skipping 7 instantiation contexts ]
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/fill.inl:93:60:   instantiated from ‘OutputIterator thrust::detail::backend::fill_n(OutputIterator, Size, const T&) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long int, T = int]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/generic/fill.h:51:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::detail::backend::generic::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/fill.inl:51:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::detail::backend::dispatch::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&, Backend) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int, Backend = thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/fill.inl:83:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::detail::backend::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int]’
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/fill.inl:34:3:   instantiated from ‘void thrust::fill(ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, const T&) [with ForwardIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, T = int]’
/home/rrob/workspace/dicol/klm/src/Map.cpp:390:49:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/for_each.inl:96:1: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘thrust::detail::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’ 
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/arch.h: At global scope:
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/arch.h:90:15: warning: inline function ‘size_t thrust::detail::backend::cuda::arch::compute_capability()’ used but never defined
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Map.dir/Map.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Map.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: The particular file containing the call to fill() is compiled using NVCC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong compilation path because the file extension you have for the code is incorrect:

```
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Map.dir/Map.cpp.o] Error 1
```

The solution is to name the file to `Map.cu` rather than `Map.ccp`. The .cu extension tells nvcc that there is device code in the file and the device compiler trajectory is required. `thrust::fill` invokes a kernel and brings in device code, whereas vector declarations only use API calls which the host compiler can deal with. This is why the compilation only fails with the `thrust::fill` call in place.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.  (I wasted hours on this one.)  I was developing code in the Map.cpp file with the intent of moving it to a map.cu file.  So many of my other THRUST commands would compile fine in the cpp file,... I never would have caught it.  Up until now, I thought NVCC didn't care about the file extension.

Comment: @Doug Are you sure you are using the device pointers when using other thrust commands ?